# Django avatar app?

Tags: django, avatar

not able to view my pictures on the template
1)added avatar to installed apps
2) edited urls
3) added code in temlplates

kindly help if any other change is required?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not setup the media and static url settings in settings.py either that or you have not configured the HTTP server you are running to display images from those locations (assuming you are not using the dev server). Obviously it is hard to help with no information so perhaps providing a bit more might be useful (some code for example).